# Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss'such file or directory not found

Tags: web, github-pages, portfolio

I am encountering an issue while using Jekyll on GitHub Pages. The error message states: "Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss': No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs." The `style.scss` file is missing from my project, and I need assistance to resolve this issue. My GitHub repository link is: https://github.com/Jehan057/JehanEngineer.github.io. I have already tried fixing things by downloading a separate style.scss file from somewhere else and also I changed the name of main.css to style.css. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!